# Colorama Formatting Strings

Tags: python, colorama, termcolor

I am back with another problem with my program but this time its with Colorama, and Termcolor(Both of which are being used together)

The format I am looking for: Colors Module [LOADED] 
Please not the word "Loaded" and ONLY that word should be green

The script:

```
print 'Colors module',"[", cprint("LOADED","green"),"]"
```

I want to know how I could get it to format the way I am hoping for

Currently the word loaded is green like it should however its the ending ] thats the problem, it is on the next line

```
Colors module [LOADED
 None ]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? (PS if you recommend another module instead of those to, I am using python version 2.7)

Comment: Why do you use `cprint` when Colorama already can inject color into your print statement?

Comment: Because I use termcolor along side of Colorama. I am used to this method of doing things.

Comment: why do you need termcolor and colorama?

Comment: I cant remember fully, however its mostly due to compatibility or something.I found the use of the two together in the way I use it here on stack overflow, I can find the page to show you. Its explained better here:                                          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858567/why-does-termcolor-output-control-characters-instead-of-colored-text-in-the-wind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting a line break is because the `cprint` call gives you one. I'm not sure what you need colorama for, the following works for me, albeit in python 3 (which you should be using):

```py
from termcolor import colored
print("Colors module [" + colored("LOADED", "green") + "]")
```

[image]

Comment: Well then, I forgot I asked this question, I ended up forgetting I asked this and figured it out myself, however because you went through the effort, have a nice check mark :)