# Why does termcolor not work in python27 windows?

Tags: python-2.7, termcolor

I just installed termcolor for python 2.7 on windows8.1. When I try to print colored text, I get the strange output.

```
from termcolor import colored
print colored('Hello world','red')
```

Here is the result:

```
[31mHello world[0m
```

Help to get out from this problem.Thanks,In advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does termcolor output control characters instead of colored text in the Windows console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858567/why-does-termcolor-output-control-characters-instead-of-colored-text-in-the-wind)

Answer (score 2):

See this [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-terminal-in-python) post.

It basically says that in order to get the escape sequences working in Windows, you need to run os.system('color') first.

For example:

```
import termcolor
import os
os.system('color')
print(termcolor.colored("Stack Overflow", "green")
```

Answer (score 0):

`termcolor` or `colored` works perfectly fine under python 2.7 and I can't replicate your error on my Mac/Linux.

If you looks into the source code of `colored`, it basically print the string in the format as

```
\033[%dm%s\033[0m' % (COLORS[color], text)
```

Somehow your terminal environment does not recognise the non-printing escape sequences that is used in the unix/linux system for setting the foreground color of xterm.