# Termcolor seems to be working in IDE but not in CMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, termcolor

`from termcolor import colored, cprint`

`cprint("TESTING TERMCOLOR", "red")`

This code is working in my IDE (Pycharm) but not on my terminal.
Gives coloured output in IDE but not in terminal.
This is the Output in terminal:

`[31mTESTING TERMCOLOR[0m`

Comment: Please add what os you are using. If you are using Windows 7, the CMD doesnt support ANSI control codes. Other package like `colorama` has a way to convert ANSI code to Windows native DLL call, so the color will show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by cmd you mean the standard windows terminal, I fear termcolor does not work out of the box there. See e.g. [Why does termcolor not work in python27 windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922073/why-does-termcolor-not-work-in-python27-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [Why does termcolor output control characters instead of colored text in the Windows console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858567/why-does-termcolor-output-control-characters-instead-of-colored-text-in-the-wind). https://github.com/tartley/colorama seems to be a workaround to make it work there