# Text Blink(when printing) in Python 2.7

Tags: python, text

I'm trying to get a text blink in python . I found this method:

```
from termcolor import colored, cprint
cprint('\nJames Everleigh', 'red', attrs=['blink'])
```

but when i compile it i get some sort weird text:

```
""[5m[31m
James Everleigh[0m ""
```

What do I need to use to get the desired output?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does termcolor output control characters instead of colored text in the Windows console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858567/why-does-termcolor-output-control-characters-instead-of-colored-text-in-the-wind)

Answer (score 0):

[5m[31m and [0m are are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for format and color. You have to enable your terminal to interpret them.

Comment: @TibiGhimbas What terminal emulator are you using? In many terminals blinking is just bright or bold text.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows powershell you need to 
`pip colorama` and `import init from colorama` and run it like this:

```
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored
init()
print(colored("text","red"))
```