# I can not properly output the color text in python

Tags: python, termcolor

when use this code:

```
from termcolor2 import colored

print(colored('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green'))
```

---

my output in terminal is :`←[31mhello←[0m ←[32mworld←[0m`

whats the problem?

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858567/why-does-termcolor-output-control-characters-instead-of-colored-text-in-the-wind -- you need colorama module and colorama.init()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colorama` module

```
pip install colorama
```

Code:

```py
from colorama import init, Fore, Back

init(convert=True)    # Initialize colorama module
print(Fore.RED + 'Your Text' + Fore.RESET)    # Red colored output
print(Back.GREEN + 'Your Text' + Back.RESET)  # Green Backgroung Output
```

More Details - https://pypi.org/project/colorama/